# quit loop on JS event

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

so im a little rusty with my JS, but here is my code...
basically i have an image, that on mouseover, it cycles through a hidden div full of other images... fading it out, replacing the src, and fading back in.  it works great.  but once it gets through all the images, i want it to start back over and keep looping through them until the mouseout event stops it.

i thought i could just call the function again from within the function `cycle_images($(current_image));`, but that leads to the browser freaking out, understandably.  what is a good method to accomplish this?

```
$.fn.image_cycler = function(options){
  // default configuration properties
  var defaults = {
    fade_delay:     150,
    image_duration: 1500,
    repeatCycle:    true,
  };
  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

  this.each(function(){
    var product     = $(this);
    var image       = $('div.image>a.product_link>img', product);
    var description = $('div.image>div.description', product);
    var all_images  = $('div.all_images', product);
    var next_image  = ($(all_images).find('img[src="' + $(image).attr('src') + '"]').next('img').attr('src')) ? $(all_images).find('img[src="' + $(image).attr('src') + '"]').next('img') : $(all_images).children('img').first();;

    // mouseover
    image.fadeOut(options.fade_delay, function(){
      image.attr('src', next_image.attr('src'));
      image.fadeIn(options.fade_delay);
    });
    if (options.repeatCycle){
      var loop = function() {
        product.image_cycler();
      }
      setTimeout(loop,options.image_duration);
    }
  });
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.product').hover(function(){
    $(this).image_cycler();
  }, function(){
    $(this).image_cycler({repeatCycle: false});
  });
});
```

Comment: I would advise not using all images in an .each, but using `var img = $('div.image div.all_images img:first')` and continuing on with  `var img = $(this).next() || $('div.image div.all_images img:first');` (or somthing of the sort).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want it to re-cycle and stop on mouseout.

After you define the cycle_images() function, add a flag, repeatCycle

```
cycle_images.repeatCycle = true;
```

At the end of the cycle_images function, add a recursive call with a timeout

```
if (this.repeatCycle) {
   var f = function() {
      return cycle_images.apply(this, [$current_image]);
   }
   setTimeout(f,50);
}
```

Then in mouseout,

```
cycle_images.repeatCycle = false;
```

Comment: so i completely modified my code with both your (brad's suggestions), however i am now having issues stopping the cycler!  my mouseout function is creating a new instance of the image_cycler function instead of setting that option.  i think this code is much cleaner, but how can i break the loop on mouseout?

Comment: oops. typo.  i meant 'your (AND brad's suggestions)'.  the recursive call work's wonderfully.